# Shadow Image doesn't work on the first viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement a seperatorline between the navigationbar and the content. I found a UIImage extension, which creates an image with a color.

```
    extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

I put this in the viewWillAppear like that:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: constants.lightBlue)
```

This works well, if I click on an entry in my collection view and come back to the initial view controller. However, it doesn't get loaded on the first startup of the app.

Comment: call it in view did load.

Comment: @SourLeangChhean I did that and also tried it with viewdidappear.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create simple UIView with backgroundColor? You can place it by frame or constraint and it should work well.

I mean, you can even create it in Storyboard and don't use code at all

Comment: I am using a TableViewController so I can't really put something in between navigationbar and tableview